# Catel MVVM + Json.NET model

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, json.net, catel

I'm having problem with connecting Catel framework with Json.NET.

I have prepared a model class with will be created by deserialization:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class PlaceRabat : ModelBase
{
    #region Fields

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new object from scratch.
    /// </summary>
    public PlaceRabat()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new object based on <see cref="SerializationInfo"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info"><see cref="SerializationInfo"/> that contains the information.</param>
    /// <param name="context"><see cref="StreamingContext"/>.</param>
    protected PlaceRabat(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    // TODO: Define your custom properties here using the modelprop code snippet

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the property value.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the Name property so it is known in the class.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly PropertyData NameProperty = RegisterProperty("Name", typeof (string), null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the property value.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the Value property so it is known in the class.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly PropertyData ValueProperty = RegisterProperty("Value", typeof (string), null);

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the field values of this object. Override this method to enable
    /// validation of field values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="validationResults">The validation results, add additional results to this list.</param>
    protected override void ValidateFields(List<IFieldValidationResult> validationResults)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the field values of this object. Override this method to enable
    /// validation of field values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="validationResults">The validation results, add additional results to this list.</param>
    protected override void ValidateBusinessRules(List<IBusinessRuleValidationResult> validationResults)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

After trying to deserialize it by Json.NET:

```
List<PlaceRabat > items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PlaceRabat >>(jsonString);
```

I'm getting exception:

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: serializationInfo"}

Could you please tell me how should it look like to connect Json deserializable class with Catel MVVM framework?

**Edit:**

Here you have stackTrace from a moment when I'm executing **Deserialization**:

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateSerializationCallback>b__0(Object o, StreamingContext context)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.InvokeOnDeserialized(Object o, StreamingContext context)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.OnDeserialized(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Object value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at Services.JsonService.Deserialize(String jsonString)
```

And StackTrace of **InnerException**:

```
   at Catel.Argument.IsNotNull(String paramName, Object paramValue)
   at Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Binary.BinarySerializationContextInfo..ctor(SerializationInfo serializationInfo)
   at Catel.Data.ModelBase.OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
```

Comment: Please create an issue at the official issue tracker so it can be fixed:
http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: Any workaround for now?

Comment: Not that I know. If you provide the callstack so I know where the serializationInfo is null, then it is easier to debug.